# Varying density of UISlider values?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Do you have some neat idea/solution on how I could achieve varying density for values in UISlider. By this I mean we would have 20 steps in the left half of UISlider and 100 step on the right half of UISlider. That means the min value would be 0, the max value would be 120. but they would not be distributed evenly, but the left part would be much less dense.
Like that>

|0---------------20---------------120|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a linear progression from 0-20 in the first half and a linear progression from 20-120 in the second half then do the following:

Set the slider's range from 0 - 200. Then when you need your desired value, use the following formula to convert the slider's value to your desired value:

```
if (slider.value <= 100) {
    desiredValue = slider.value / 5.0;
} else {
    desiredValue = slider.value - 80;
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter - Why the down vote? This was chosen as the accepted answer. Please explain what it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this recently using n-th root math to determine my `UISlider`'s position.  I have a couple of sliders that indicate minimums and maximums on a range, but since most of the time these values tend towards the lower range of the full spectrum, I wanted to put more emphasis on it.  To achieve this, I used (in my case) a square root function to calculate the slider's position:

```
slider.value = sqrt(intValue/127.f);
```

`127` is the maximum value in my range, and this gives me a higher emphasis on the lower range of the value spectrum.  With this, I hit half full on the slider bar with a value of only 32, instead of 64.  You can generalize this to something like:

```
slider.value = pow(intValue/127.f, (1/root));
```

where `root` is another variable for you to use.  The higher the value of `root` the more steep the curve will be in the beginning, and shallower near the end.

If instead you want to read the slider's current position as a value you just have to invert that function above:

```
myValue = (slider.value*slider.value) * 127;
```

Again, you can generalize to:

```
myValue = pow(slider.value, root) * maxValue;
```

Comment: My value distribution does not follow a concrete mathematical function or algorithm unfortunately.